# Empaquetar aplicación en C# y PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql

Tengo una aplicación desarrollada con C# y el gestor de base de datos es PostgreSQL, para conectarme uso Npgsql y la cadena de conexión es:

```
cadConexion = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=...;Database=Tienda;";
```

Quisiera saber cómo puedo empaquetar la aplicación de forma que con un ejecutable funcione completamente (incluida la base de datos), creo que es evidente y está demás decir que es la primera vez que intento realizar esto. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La db requiere que instales un servicio, no recomendaria que la incluyas como parte del instalador de la applicacion.
Si puedes usar ClickOnce, Setup Project o InstallShield para crear el instalador de la aplicacion, pero la db dejala por separado, esta requiere pasos diferenciados, no solo es instalar el motor sino que debes ejecutar scripts

[Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)

Ademas la db por lo general se instala en una pc separada que actuara de servidor de base de datos, a la cual se podran conectar desde varios cliente